# Datatable plugin fails to customize dynamically loaded tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In my single page application, all static resources, js files are loaded by the home page. Then the table is dynamically loaded on a user click. However, the datatable customization is not applied on the newly loaded table div element.

The code in its simplest form is,

```
<div>Home Page</div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="datatable.js"></script>
<script src="datatable_jquery_ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $("div").on('click', function(e){
      console.log("div is clicked")
      $("div").html("<table><tr><td>jasmine</td><td>december</td></tr></table>")
      $("div table").dataTable()
    })
</script>
```

When the user clicks the div element, the table is loaded but the code, `$("div table").dataTable()` has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing thead and tfoot tags. dataTable need those tags for initialization.

For example:

```
$("div").html("<table><thead><tr><td>jasmine</td><td>december</td></tr></thead><tfoot></tfoot></table>")
```